# CircleCI fails to evaluate TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, circleci

I have a project that is typescript in the front end as well as the back end. All tests are passing locally, but, when pushing to a branch on github it always fails at the first sign of TypeScript (in the back end, right now I'm just focusing on back end testing).

> ```
> SyntaxError: /home/circleci/project/server/src/User-Server/server.ts: Unexpected token (16:35)
> ```

```
  14 | app.use(apiRoutes);
  15 | 
> 16 | module.exports = app.listen(PORT, (): void => {
     |                                    ^
  17 |   console.log(` Server listening on port ${PORT} - ${ENV} environment`);
  18 | });
  19 |
```

Here is my config.yml:

```
version: 2
jobs: 
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.15.3

    # working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      #download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
```

I have posted this also to the [CircleCI discussion forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/tests-passing-locally-but-failing-with-circleci-typescript-issue/32116).

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "../",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["test", "**/*/spec.ts", "**/*/test.ts"]
}
```

my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  roots: ['src'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

Comment: CircleCI itself is just a CI system, and has no capacity to evaluate TypeScript. There is probably some detail missing from your question - can TypeScript be run from the `.ts` source? Or do you need to transpile it first, to JavaScript? What system is giving the `SyntaxError` above - is that from NPM?

Comment: I guess how can I give Circle Ci a babel so that it will translate it to regular js for circle ci to be able to run the tests.

Comment: I don't use TypeScript, but I assume that would be committed to your project in the same way. Is it a config file, like `babel.json`? If things are working locally, but not remotely, then there is something different - maybe your Node version.

Comment: what would be nice is if circle ci just used the test runner rather than circleci itself. I'm so very confused by this

Comment: You've misunderstood hosted CI, I think. It is just a farm of Linux servers with a nice web UI on top (as is Bitbucket Pipelines, GitLab CI, etc). You have to treat it as if it were a local machine, and debug it as if it were a local machine.

Comment: So, again, do you have different versions of Node running between local/remote? You _are_ doing something differently between the two, and you have to find out what that is.

Comment: @halfer thank you, yes I do, the version on my machine is 12.7.0 and the one on CircleCi is 10.15.3, I am currently trying to see how to upgrade the node version that CircleCI spins up

Comment: Change `circleci/node:10.15.3` to `node:12.7` in your config - I've just checked that this image exists. It is the default Node build rather than one from CircleCI - but I've never understood what a CircleCI image offers that community ones do not. All of my upstream images are from `docker`, for example.

Comment: yea, changed it, and still the same issue. for the life of me I can't figure out why it is working finally locally but not remotely.

Comment: Maybe you need to keep searching for changes. Try checking out the project into a completely new local folder, and run it again - perhaps you have a file not under version control that is getting it to work.